# Get ID from Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been sitting all night trying to figure out how to authorize a user via Facebooks API, just to get their User ID.
I've tried almost all of the tips and ideas from S/O, 5 pages of "Google guides" and the Facebook Developer Guide but nothing seems to work for me! If anyone would be so kind and make a step-by-step guide how to get this to work!

Is Open Graph a must for this? I tried it aswell, didn't work with nor without it. I already have my App (maybe not the right settings there?) and the PHP SDK

*( `$uid = $facebook->getUser();` etc. not giving me any help at all. )*

Thanks in advance!

This code for example is not working, I found it here on S/O and he said it was working flawlessly for him!

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '########',
  'secret' => '##########################',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$req_perms = "publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,email,read_stream"; 
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=> 1,'fbconnect' => 0,'req_perms' => $req_perms));
$user_info = null;
if (!$session) 
    { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";exit;}
else{
     try {  $user_info = $facebook->api('/me');  } 
     catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
         { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>"; exit;}
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$user_name=$user_info['name'];
echo "Hi $user_name ! Your Facebook ID is: ".$user_info['id']."<br/>"; 
echo "Hi $user_name ! Your E-mail Address is: ".$user_info['email']."<br/>"; 
echo "Thanks for accepting our application.";
//print_r($user_info);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit: Thanks for all the quick responses, I finally got it working! I was on the right track all along..**

**Step 1 :** Make a link like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

This authorizes the user with the facebook app, which is needed for step2.

**Step 2 :** Implement this code snippet.

```
require_once('facebook.php');

$fb_app_id = "APP_ID";
$fb_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$fb_app_url = "APP_URL";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_photos',
    'redirect_uri' => $fb_app_url
));

$facebook_user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Thank you **@KevinCogill** and **@JuicyScripter** for the tips!

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using at the moment?

Comment: Whoa I've tried so many, let me see if I can find the one that was least complicated. Added code snippet now!

Comment: Where and how did you use the link created in "Step 1"? Is this code still valid to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require_once('facebook/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_photos',
    'redirect_uri' => $fb_app_url
));

$facebook_user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: `$facebook_user_id` will be empty until user visits `$facebook_login_url` first.

Comment: Will this code snippet do all the work? After i set the app id variables?

Comment: It just returns 0, what could be the cause of this? I got this result many times yesterday aswell.

Comment: yup, juicy scripter is right; $facebook_user_id will only get the id if the user has logged in. i usually use an if(empty($facebook_user_id)) to catch false/0 values.
and it will do most of the work... you'll need to have a user click $facebook_login_url and auth. then $facebook_user_id will populate.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook already did it for you:

You must read [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and see [examples](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)

**Update (notes on updated code sample):**
You using `getSession` which isn't really exists in latest version of Facebook PHP-SDK and `req_perms` is called `scope` now. Did you read Facebook documentation or tutorials posted somewhere else? Facebook changing things frequently most of tutorials you'll find in other sources will be outdated very fast. Better to get info from official source (even if it's not the greatest quality)